# Проблема с CORS в Laravel API - Angular. Сервер работает на NGINX. Фронт на основном домене, бек на поддомене

Tags: laravel, angular, cors, error404

Прошу помощи в данной ситуации.

Сайт разработан в связке Backend = Laravel-8-REST-API, Frontend = Angular 11.

В качестве сервера на localhost использован NGINX.

API лежит на локальной машине на отдельном домене (внутри локального хоста), Angular стучится с localhost:4200. Все работает отлично.

CORS в Laravel настроен стандартной с 7 версии CORS config.

До этого сайт был выгружен на хостинг. Соответственно API на поддомен api.site.com, фронт на site.com

Все работало отлично.
Но вот появилась задача реализации функционала, который не доступен на хостинге и пришлось брать VDS.

Потратив время на установку ПО, подключив требуемые модули, казалось бы и все. Но...

Нарисовалась проблема. При попытке отправить или получить текстовые данные все отрабатывает отлично.
Но только пытаюсь отправить какой-либо файл, тут же на этот метод ругается CORS и запрос не проходит.

Не могу понять в чем проблема? Может есть гуру который сталкивался с подобным.
Сервер и его конфиги не моя тема (до настоящего момента).

Сервер работает на NGINX, для домена и поддомена созданы А-записи, висят на одном IP.

Оба: домен и поддомен защищены сертификатом Let’s Encrypt.

Ниже конфиг основного домена на нем клиент Angular:

```
    server {
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /var/www/httpdocs/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

---

Далее прилагаю код конфига поддомена на котором располагается API - Laravel 8:

```
server {
    server_name api.site.com www.api.site.com;
    root /var/www/api/public;


    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;        
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.api.site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = api.site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name api.site.com www.api.site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

---

Выложил именно конфиги хостов, так-как предполагаю проблема в неумелой настройке данных сущностей.
Прошу помощи ребята и девчата.
Возможно потребуются другие данные, с радостью их предоставлю.

Answer (score 0):

Даю ответ. Все было до банального просто.

Файлы не загружались из-за стандартных ограничений на сервере.
Увеличить размер файла загружаемого и размер пост данных принимаемых.
Так же выставить разрешения адекватно и права на пользователя `www-data`.

По умолчанию сервер при реализации данной конструкции angular - laravel выдает в консоль только ошибку CORS, чем путает. На самом деле проблема крылась совершенно в другом.